# Remove leading 0 from date and month in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

i have an array in php like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
      string(4) "2019"     // year
    [1]=>
      string(2) "07"       //month
    [2]=>
      string(2) "02"       //day
 }
```

i want to remove leading 0 from my day and month field and get back another array with new values. i have used `number_format()` but i don't know how to use it with array.

New Output should be:-

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
      string(4) "2019"   //year
   [1]=>
      string(2) "7"   //month
   [2]=>
      string(2) "2"   // day
  }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: From where you got this array of string for date?

Comment: getting it from input type date form field @Rishi

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: I am not the downvoter. What exact value you are getting from date input text

Comment: data i am getting from date input text is  `2019-07-02`

Comment: I am guessing you got this in a php variable and want to convert it into `2019-7-2`  ?

Comment: yes. i need it like `2019-7-2` and Thanks , i got the answer to that too

Comment: Thats nice, Just giving you another way to do.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$vals = array_map(function($x) { return (int)$x;}, $vals);
```

Comment: Well, @AaronBelchamber, its really the same process. array_map() and array_filter() make for very clean code, though. I use them regularly for stuff like this.

Comment: Slightly less efficient would be to ltrim($x,"0"), if you wanted to keep it a string. Don't see why you would for this situation though.

Comment: Actually, it was asked for an array with `string` values, so the usage of `ltrim()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert date with zero leading to flat value ,you can also use date function.

```
  <?php
      echo date("Y-n-j",strtotime("2019-07-02"));
  ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/838978

Refer this : 
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Just cycle through and force integer values.

```
 $dateArr=
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
          string(4) "2019"     // year
        [1]=>
          string(2) "07"       //month
        [2]=>
          string(2) "02"       //day
     };

     $newDateArr=array();
     foreach($dateArr as $elem){
        $newDateArr[]=(int)$elem;
     }

     // $newDateArr is the new array without leading zeroes.
```